# how to use llvm compile a dataset file,which is bigclonebench

Tags: llvm

i want to use llvm compile the source code in the database file(the type of h2dataset)into an IR file,how can i complie.(ps：i use bigclonebench dataset.）

in addition i want to reproduce  the experimental process of this paper（paper name:Neural Code Comprehension: A LearnableRepresentation of Code Semantics t)

Comment: What is the source code? Is it C or rust or some other language for which there already exists an LLVM frontend? Does it matter that it's in a database or could you extract the source code into files and compile them with a tool like clang?